# Require de un require con una función

Tags: php

Fichero inicial:

```
require_once '../../translator.php';
translateTo('es');
//Resto del código
```

Fichero translator.php:

```
function translateTo($language){
    if ($language == 'es'){
        require_once 'lang_es.php';

    }else{
        require_once 'lang_en.php';
        $language = 'en';
    }
}
```

Y por ejemplo, en el fichero lang_es.php (que está al mismo nivel que translator.php):

```
 $lang = array(
    'key' => 'palabra en español'
 );
```

Cuando intento hacer un 'echo $lang['key']' en el fichero inicial, no me devuelve nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al hacer la inclusión dentro de una función el ámbito del fichero incluido se queda restringido a dicha función.

Tienes más información en la documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php)

Podrías hacer:

**En translator.php**

```
function translateTo($language){
    if ($language == 'es'){
        return 'lang_es.php';

    }else{
        return 'lang_en.php';
    }
}
```

**y en fichero inicial**

```
require_once '../../translator.php';
require_once '../../'.translateTo('es');
```